# GCC bug or UB? Should this code compile?

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc4.7

The code below compiles fine with clang, but does not compile with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (tried 4.1.2, 4.5.4 and 4.7.2):

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    struct B { };
};

template <typename T>
bool operator==(typename A<T>::B const& b, T const&  t);

enum { BAR };

template <typename T>
bool test()
{
    return 0 == BAR;
}
```

The error message from GCC 4.7.2 is:

```
a.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct A<<anonymous enum> >’:
a.cpp:12:6:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T> bool operator==(const typename A<T>::B&, const T&) [with T = <anonymous enum>]’
a.cpp:19:17:   required from here
a.cpp:6:12: error: ‘<anonymous enum>’ is/uses anonymous type
a.cpp:6:12: error:   trying to instantiate ‘template<class T> struct A<T>::B’
a.cpp:6:12: error: ‘<anonymous enum>’ is/uses anonymous type
a.cpp:6:12: error:   trying to instantiate ‘template<class T> struct A<T>::B’
```

Is [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) correct in rejecting the code, or am I hitting its bug?

P.S. I've seen this error while trying to build one of opensource projects. I tried to make smallest possible example that reproduces it.

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 both compile it.

Comment: What function are you calling? Could you please post the entire a.cpp?

Comment: @AndersJohansson This **is** entire a.cpp. I'm not calling any function.

Comment: Looks like a g++ bug to me. Comeau online compiles the code as well.

Comment: SFINAE should kick in and use the normal enum-to-int comparison.

Comment: @iv_, maybe I'm missing something but there's no `main` and template functions are only instantiated when called, so if you're not calling any function, this a.cpp should definitely not compile, nor do anything.

Comment: Can you submit the function call that causes the errors because  it compiles fine in Ideone.com.

Comment: @SChepurin: when I tried it, ideone.com throws the errors described.

Comment: @AndersJohansson: the code might not compile to a complete program, but it can still be compilable (use the `-c` option to just compile without linking).  An empty file will compile successfully.

Comment: @GManNickG: I don't see any of these templates being instantiated - why would SFINAE kick in?

Comment: @Michael Burr "when I tried it, ideone.com throws the errors described."- And would you kindly submit the link to ideone.com with your test?

Comment: http://ideone.com/ZHK1W2

Comment: @Michael Burr - What do you test? Does the order matter? Where is main()?

Comment: `g++ a.cpp -c -std=c++0x` compiles fine. The bug seems to be fixed in the c++11 specific parts of g++.

Comment: i am not sure that this is a bug. in c++11, they simply changed the rules to be less strict. There are several rules that relate linkage-less entities with types that have linkage and restrict their relation in certain ways. Will read the relevant parts of the spec later..

Comment: @MichaelBurr: `0 == BAR` should be compiled during phase one, no instantiation needed.

Comment: It's certainly not a bug, it's a change in C++11 and implemented as of gcc 4.4 if you specify the correct language version (but, only then, which is, again, correct).

Answer (score 1):

It is not valid C++ according to the original standard:

14.3.1 of the standard says:

> 2 A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a
>   type compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a 
>   template argument for a template type-parameter.  [Example: ...

However I believe this was restriction was removed by the latest C++11 standard. That may explain why some compilers accept it while others reject it.

Comment: As GManNickG pointed out in the comments, SFINAE. The failing overload should be silently eliminated.

Comment: I confirm that `g++` is not compiling it until you ask for C++11 specs: `g++ -std=c++11 -o foo.o -c foo.c`